# typescript get value from stringObject that has stringInterpolation and fill the interpolation;

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, string-interpolation

Example:

```
const objectA = {
  a: `a ${fruit} is red`,
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

const fruit = 'strawberry';

console.log(objectA['a']);
```

Console:

```
Error: fruit is not defined
```

I'm wondering if this is even possible.

If it is how could I do this.

Comment: initialize fruit before object A. It will work

Comment: const fruit = 'strawberry';

const objectA = {
  a: `a ${fruit} is red`,
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to do it in the right order:

```
const fruit = 'strawberry';

const objectA = {
  a: `a ${fruit} is red`,
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(objectA['a']);
```